# Is there a vba code that can change the content of a copied cell?

Tags: excel, vba

My current code finds the last row and copy-pastes it to a new row. However, I would like to be able to increment the week number. Is there a way I could that? So instead fo WK 4 at the end, I would like it to be WK5.
I posted an image for guidance

[image]

This is the code:

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Rows(LR).Select
Selection.Copy
Rows(LR).Select

 Cells(LR + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
Cells(LR + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to include your code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Dim LR As Long, num As Long

with ActiveSheet

    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Rows(LR).Copy


     .Cells(LR + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
     .Cells(LR + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     Application.CutCopyMode = False

     num = CLng(replace(.Cells(LR + 1, 1).Value,"WK ","")) + 1 'get next week number
     .Cells(LR + 1, 1).Value = "WK " & num                     'replace value with new week
End With

End Sub
```